# Is there any way to copy byte by byte from a file and play it using videoView in android?

Tags: android

I have tried this but it's not working. It copies all the bytes at once and play it. But i want to copy byte by byte from a file and play this video during/while receiving...

**Some Code**

```
 tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/" +"temp.mp4");

        int length=0;
        byte[] vidBytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        try {
            //while (length<100)
            //{
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                fileInputStream.read(vidBytes,0,vidBytes.length);
                fileInputStream.close();
                videoPlayer.setVideoPath(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
                Toast.makeText(this,tempFile.getPath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                videoPlayer.start();
                length++;
            //}


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            fileOutputStream.write(vidBytes,0,50,vidBytes.length);
            fileOutputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

what the hell are you doing? the fileInputStream is practically useless ! you read the bytes into the byte array vidBytes, but never actually use it anywhere, videoView doesn't require you to open an input stream, all videoView requires is the path to the file and the videoView code takes care of opening the stream and loading the data efficiently.

Also why are you writing the same Byte array that you read just few statements ago not modify it and write it back to the SAME FILE!? What are you trying to accomplish here?

P.S This is all you need to do to play the mp4 file in the videoview

```
tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/" +"temp.mp4");
videoPlayer.setVideoPath(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
Toast.makeText(this,tempFile.getPath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
videoPlayer.start();
```

Comment: I want to copy bytes of a file already present in my device and play video using bytes.

Comment: @AbdulBasit copy bytes to where?

Comment: and do what with it? whats the purpose of holding this huge data in memory?

Comment: Basically i want to receive data in bytes using sockets and play the bytes.

Comment: @AbdulBasit But there is no socket here, you are just reading bytes from a file

Comment: Yes i know, but i am considering these bytes to be coming from a socket, once i will do this i will move onto the sockets.

Comment: @AbdulBasit in that case edit your question and convey your intentions clearly! also this post might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372319/videoview-playing-a-file-while-it-is-received-via-socket

Comment: Can you please edit your answer.. just play specfic bytes from byte array?